# How do I view and manage all nodes by a specific user in Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I would like to see all nodes created by a specific user so I can delete all of them. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's ok, a quick Google search let me to the [Content Management Filter](http://drupal.org/project/cmf) module.

Answer (score 2):

That's good to hear.  I'd also suggest the [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module.